# compiling wxWidgets with c++0x flags

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, reinterpret-cast

While trying to compile `wxWidgets-2.9.1` from source with `c++0x` flags using `gcc-4.6`. I came across an error

`narrowing conversion of '128' from 'int' to 'char' inside { } [-fpermissive]` 
in the file `src/gtk/dcclient.cpp`. The error comes from the following files:

1. src/gtk/bdiag.xbm
2. src/gtk/cdiag.xbm
3. src/gtk/fdiag.xbm
4. src/gtk/horiz.xbm
5. src/gtk/verti.xbm
6. src/gtk/cross.xbm

This is a known bug.
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/12575
So I did as required and the program is compiling okay.

Basically, there are two kinds of fix that the `diff` file has

//in the file **dcclient.h**

1. hatches[i] = gdk_bitmap_create_from_data(NULL, **bdiag_bits**, bdiag_width, bdiag_height); 
   hatches[i] = gdk_bitmap_create_from_data(NULL, **reinterpret_cast< const char* >(bdiag_bits)**, bdiag_width, bdiag_height);

   //in the file **bdiag.xbm** and similar fixes in all the *.xbm files
2. static **char** bdiag_bits[] = {

   static **unsigned char** bdiag_bits[] = { 
   0x80, 0x80, 0x40, 0x40, 0x20, 0x20, 0x10, 0x10, 0x08, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 
   0x02, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x80, 0x80, 0x40, 0x40, 0x20, 0x20, 0x10, 0x10, 
   0x08, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 0x02, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01};

I understand the second `fix` but I could not understand the first one. Why do we need to do a `reinterpret_cast< const char* >` The function `gdk_bitmap_create_from_data` is declared like this:

```
typedef char   gchar;//in some other header file
```

`GdkBitmap* gdk_bitmap_create_from_data  (GdkDrawable *drawable, const gchar *data, gint       width, gint height);`

while a few lines later in the same file **dcclient.cpp** the following call to the `gdk_bitmap_create_from_data` doesn't give any error.

```
char* data = new char[data_size];
//...
GdkPixmap* pixmap = gdk_bitmap_create_from_data(mask, data, dst_w, dst_h);
```

Now here no typecast is required. Why do we need to do a reinterpret_cast on `static unsigned char*`?

Comment: what's gchar defined to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsigned char`, `signed char` and `char` (also known as 'plain char') are three different types. There is no conversion between `unsigned char*` and `char*`.

Comment: so that means `reinterpret_cast` from `unsigned char` to `char` should be used only when the `unsigned char` has ASCII values between `0` and `127`?

Comment: @Aditya Formally, the result of the cast is implementation defined. There's no real guideline other than "you'd better know that you're doing", and I don't know what's the intent here was other than a quick and dirty hack.

Answer (score 1):

`data` has type `unsigned char*`, but `gdk_bitmap_create_from` expects a `const char*`.  `reinterpret_cast` is dealing with the signedness mismatch.